# Does NHibernate support mapping from SQL Views?

Tags: sql, database, nhibernate, view

Does NHibernate support mapping of SQL VIEWS?  Any examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can update or insert to views in SQL Server if certain conditions are met, see the [Updateable Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) section in the documentation. I know this applies to SQL Server 2005+, I don't know about earlier versions.

If the view is not updateable, you can declare the mapping as read-only.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, just use your view name instead of the table name in your mapping config.  Of course it will throw an exception if you try to update though.

e.g.:

```
<class name="someclass" table="vw_someview">
...
</class>
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: Yes.

Just put your view's name in the places where normally in all the examples is written a table name. That's it. Views and tables are interchangeable - as long as the view is writeable without constraints...

Thomas